# Hiding Shield ASP.NET MVC charts using JS function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shieldui

I am using Shield ASP.NET MVC charts on a page. I need the charts to initially show data for my visitors, and I need to provide the user the possibility to hide the charts by clicking on the corresponding button(s). For this purpose I use the following function:

```
<script>
    function HideChart() {
        document.getElementById("DataSpot").innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

And I am placing the charts as follows:

```
<p id="DataSpot">
@(Html.ShieldChart()
    .Name("chart")
    .PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("Profile Hits"))
    .Export(false)
    .AxisX(axisX => axisX
    ………..
)
</p>
<button onclick="HideChart()">Hide Chart</button>
```

The problem is, that when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2492467,

Do you need to hide the chart or do you need to wipe out its content? If just hiding the chart, the approach suggested by Chris would work just fine. However, if you need to irrevocably wipe out the chart from the page altogether, then clearing its content is not enough. Only removing the rendered chart markup would open the door for memory leaks, as references to the DOM nodes may remain in the chart javascript component.

A better approach would be to find the javascript component instance and call its `.destroy()` method. This will ensure the component is fully destroyed and no memory is leaked:

```
$("#DataSpot").swidget().destroy();
```

Note that you still need to give your chart a name using the MVC wrapper's `.Name("DataSpot")` method just like Ed suggests. This will give your chart's HTML element an ID that you can use with jQuery to find the chart instance.

The `.swidget()` method is a standard jQuery extension method added by the Shield UI javascript framework. It returns the javascript component instance associated with the element matched by the jQuery selector. This is how you find the chart instance.

Comment: I initially wanted to just hide the charts, but on a second thought, the user won't have the option to bring them back unless he refreshes the page. In this case, I better remove the charts altogether. Thanks for showing me how to properly do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<script>
    function HideChart() {
        document.getElementById('DataSpot').style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

You should also update your button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="HideChart()" value="Hide Chart" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something happening, obviously not the thing that you need. This is because you need to wipe out the rendered chart by referencing its  container. 
The

element is fine and if you put some text in your function and execute it you will see that it will appear on the appropriate spot. However to hide the chart you need to use it’s name. In other words the following statement:

```
 document.getElementById("DataSpot").innerHTML = "";
```

should be changed to

```
 document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = "";
```

or you may rename the chart to

```
 .Name("DataSpot ")
```

and remove the P element in both cases since it makes no use.